# Next Page Button for UIPageViewController iOS 8 - objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uipageviewcontroller

Actually I'm trying to populate gallery using PageViewController. I brought scrolling images in a view successfully but, I used **Next and Previous button in page View Controller** its not working properly i used this line of code.

```
- (IBAction)previousButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:+1];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

Since I used ***viewControllerAtIndex:+1*** at the ***- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender*** Im getting the button action working only for first click of a button action.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For the previous and next buttons you want view controller at index _currentViewControllerIndex-1_ and _currentViewControllerIndex+1_ not o and 1.

Keep track of the current index and pass next or previous index accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check this Code :-

```
- (void)changePage:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction {
    NSUInteger pageIndex = ((FooViewController *) [_pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).pageIndex;
    if (direction == UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward){
        pageIndex++;
    }else {
        pageIndex--;
    }
    YourViewController *viewController = [self  viewControllerAtIndex:pageIndex];
    if (viewController == nil) {
        return;
    }
    [_pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController] direction:direction animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

// Previous Button

```
- (IBAction)previousButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self changePage:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse];
}
```

// Next Button

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self changePage:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward];
}
```

Comment: Very good work..appreciate you answer after searching so many bad answers.

Comment: what is FooViewController,I have view controllers in an array.how to go to next vc in uipagedviewcontroller

Comment: @sat FooViewController just a UIViewController Which I have used. you can use your  custom controller name instead of FooViewController.

Comment: @Chandan i am taking vc in an array like this UIViewController *tuto1 = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstVc"];
    UIViewController *tuto2 = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondvc"];
    UIViewController *tuto3 = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsAndConditionsVC"];
    UIViewController *tuto4 = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PermissionsVC"];
    UIViewController *tuto5 = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MobileNumberVC"];

Comment: @Chandan   myViewControllers = @[tuto1, tuto2, tuto3, tuto4, tuto5]; and in pagedvc i am taking 2 buttons and if i click button in showld go to next and if i click it should come back i am not taking any buttons in vc i am using only 2 butn to do this

Answer (score 1):

Chandan's answer works perfectly.
check this in swift 3.0

```
func changePage(direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)
{
    var pageIndex = (pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] as! SliderContentVC).pageIndex
    if(direction == UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward)
    {
        pageIndex = pageIndex! + 1
    }
    else
    {
        pageIndex = pageIndex! - 1
    }
    let viewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: pageIndex!)
    if(viewController == nil)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

//Previous Click

```
@IBAction func btnGoBack_Click(_ sender: Any)
{
    self.changePage(direction: .reverse)
}
```

//back Click

```
@IBAction func btn_GoForward_Click(_ sender: Any)
{
    self.changePage(direction: .forward)
}
```

//viewControllerAtIndex method

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController?
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= MAX_COUNT)
    {
        return nil
    }
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SliderContentVC") as! SliderContentVC
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    return pageContentViewController
}
```